# WCF Service to Read Telnet Data

Tags: android, wpf, wcf, gpsd

I am using an Android phone in my application to read GPS information. The GPS information is sent over Telnet and I want to read it in my application. I will then databind the position of something like a blob to the GPS data and display a user on a map in real time.

How can I read the NMEA GPS response using WCF and consume it into my application with databinding to the position of the blob? What is the way to go about this? Mine is a desktop application and I am using WPF.

Comment: What happens when the data is sent through telnet? is the data stored in some persistent medium?

Comment: I want to poll a port and read 1 line of the response whenever I want. After the data is sent through Telnet, it is not stored anywhere. I need to read and process it in live.

Comment: then I don't understand the need for telnet, you can simply call a WCF service to send the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think WCF will solve this issue for you. I would look at something like [IP*Works](http://www.nsoftware.com/products/component/telnet.aspx) which will help you with the telnet connectivity.